# Count(*) not showing null values

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, flexible-search

I'm using Hybris by SAP for a small project and almost got this down. Im trying to find the amount of Point of Service locations with 0 Orders in the past 7 days using Flexible Search.

Here is the HAC script i used:

```
select count(*), {PointOfService.name} from {Order left join PointOfService on {Order.pointOfService} = {PointOfService.pk}} where {creationTime} >= '2019-10-01' GROUP by {PointOfService.name} order by count(*)
```

The script gives me the quanity of orders for each individual PointOfService but does not give me the PointOfService locations with '0' orders. I read that this is due to count(*) not providing NULL values. Does anyone know a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

You have a order attribute in your where(creationTime) so if there is no order for a specific point of service you wont be able to see it.
Something like that should work:

```
select count(*),
{ps.name}
from {PointOfService as ps 
left join Order as o on {o.pointOfService} = {ps.pk}}
where count({o.pk}) == 0
GROUP by {ps.name}
```